# Tortoise SVN : soft Link or Sharing Repository

Tags: svn

Hi is it possible in Tortoise SVN to create soft Link or Sharing Repository.

Explanation:
suppose I have 2 Repository 
**A** & **B**

**A**  have 2 folders **1** and **2**.

**B**  also have 2 folders  **X** and **Y**

Now the contains of folder **X** is suppose to come from folder **1** in **A** Repository.

If one update some files inside **X** directory that update should go to **A** Repository.

but when I checkout **B** Repository. all the contains should get downloded.

Answer (score 6):

I had the same problem figuring out how to add links, so I am putting this here, hopefully it might help someone. I am using Tortoise SVN interface.

In SVN, each folder has properties (e.g. externals, keywords, etc). Your linked folder will be added to the "externals" property of the containing folder. You can have multiple links defined in one "externals" property. That's why they call it multi-line.

You will need to know the URL of the folder you want to link. To find out the folder URL, right click on the folder, and select Show Properties, the URL is displayed under "Properties".

To add a linked folder, using SVN Tortoise client, follow these steps:

1) Choose the folder where you want to put your link (containing folder).

2) Right click on the folder and select "Show Properties".

3) Click on New / Externals, or click on Edit if you already have any External links defined.

4) Click on New...

5) You will see there are multiple lines. You can add more than one linked folder.

6) In URL box, paste the URL you want to link to.

7) In Local Path box, choose a folder name where the link will be stored, it should not be the entire path, just the folder name (e.g. CommonLib).

8) Pick a revision you want, or leave the HEAD revision, if you want the latest version.

9) Click OK.

10) Right click the folder where your link is, hit Refresh.

11) Your new linked folder will appear.

You can also do this using SVN commands, such as:

```
svn propset svn:externals "common -r123 https://svn.example.com/common" lib
```

That will will make a common subdirectory under the lib directory and link it to revision 123 of the external SVN URL https://svn.example.com/common.

Comment: Good tutorial, well done. One tip: If you need to do this more than once, you export and import the properties (using the same GUI)

Answer (score 3):

SVN is notoriously grumpy in dealing with softlinks/symlinks, especially if you check out the working copy to a Windows host (TSVN is Windows-only, IIRC).

However, [svn:externals](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.0/ch07s03.html) might be just what you're looking for.

Comment: Tanks a lot but this works only for Local Folders, but in SVN server. Any Help on that.